# React - WP_Mail works with jQuery but not axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I have a contact form in my React app and I am attempting to have the form send an email using WP_Mail. I am trying to do that using Axios, but I can't seem to get it to work. I get a 400 error on the `admin-ajax` call.

```
axios.post(url, {
    action: 'send_form',
    data: {
        email: 'test@test.com',
        message: 'testing'
    }
})
.then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
})
.catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

I am able to get it to work using jQuery, but I'd rather not have to use that if possible:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {action: 'send_form', email: 'test@test.com'},
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }.bind(this),
    error: function(xhr, status, err) {
        alert(err.toString());
    }.bind(this)
});
```

I think the issue has to do with the format of the payload header. When I use Axios, the data comes through as JSON payload header, but when I use jQuery it comes through as query string parameters.

Comment: Have you tried to set Content-Type as application/json for axios? Looks like the missing part.

Comment: Only jQuery sends that lame `X-Requested-With: xmlhttprequest` header. You should do the same with Axios.

Comment: Replace  data to `{action: 'send_form', email: 'test@test.com'} `    , it will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try:

```
let form_data = new FormData;
form_data.append('action', 'send_form');
form_data.append('email', 'test@test.com');
form_data.append('message', 'testing');

axios.post(url, {
  form_data
})
.then(function (response) {
   console.log(response);
 })
 .catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
 });
```

Comment: Unfortunately it still comes through as JSON